# how to write a oracle or pl/sql script to find the mean and median of the column only for 'number' datatype in table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

how to write a oracle or PLSQL script to find the column names which is 'number' datatype in table and find the average and median of that column name in table.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, but it is **not a code writing service**. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask].  You need to show yout table description (ddl), sample data, and the expected results for that data - all as text, **no images**. Also show what you have tried and those results indicating where they are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, if you're just beginning your PL/SQL *adventure*, your homework isn't as easy as it sounds. It requires you to know

- where to search for such a column (in data dictionary, `user_tab_columns` contains that info)
- how to check ALL of them (in a loop)
- how to calculate average value (using appropriate function, `avg`)
- how to actually do that (using dynamic SQL)
- how to display the result (that's the simplest part, if `dbms_output.put_line` satisfies your needs)

  - that doesn't always work, which puzzles quite a few people - you have to *enable* output (using `set serveroutput on` in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer; enable it by clicking appropriate button in your GUI tool)

The following code shows the way. Feel free to improve it.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_table_name varchar2(30) := 'EMP';
  3    l_str        varchar2(200);
  4    l_avg        number;
  5  begin
  6    for cur_r in (select column_name
  7                  from user_tab_columns
  8                  where table_name = l_table_name
  9                    and data_type = 'NUMBER'
 10                 )
 11    loop
 12      l_str := 'select avg(' || cur_r.column_name ||')' ||
 13               ' from '      || l_table_name;
 14      execute immediate l_str into l_avg;
 15
 16      dbms_output.put_line
 17        ('Average of ' || cur_r.column_name || ' = ' || l_avg);
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /
Average of EMPNO = 7726,571428571428571428571428571428571429
Average of MGR = 7739,307692307692307692307692307692307692
Average of SAL = 2073,214285714285714285714285714285714286
Average of COMM = 550
Average of DEPTNO = 22,14285714285714285714285714285714285714

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```